# first Quarter current Quarter difference

Tags: variables, dax, transition, difference

Iam fairly new to DAX and for that reason studying to catch more routine. Having problem trying to resolve. Am trying to count difference between first and the current Quarter.

```
start Q current Q diff = 
 //first quarter result for every year
 VAR firstQuarter =
    CALCULATE(
        [All Orderamount],
        dimDate[QuarterNo] = 1
    )

//all quarter sales
VAR allQuarters =
    SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            dimDate,
            dimDate[YearQuarter],
            dimDate[Quarter],
            "Total Orders In Quarter", [All Orderamount]
        ),
        [Total Orders In Quarter]
    )

RETURN
    firstQuarter - allQuarters
```

"All Orderamount" measure just basic:

```
All Orderamount = 
    SUM(factOrders[Orderamount])
```

I had a plan to first get first quarter sales
[image]

then count sales for all the quarters
[image]

And after that just deduct one from another. The thing I cant figure out is how to have firstQuarter spread out on whole matrixs but I cant figure out how to do this
[image]
...for this I also some extra measures for testing but cant figure out how to deal with context transition. Have tried removing filters from QuarterNo etc but at best it returns sales for all the data and not just for ongoing years first quarter.

or am I thinking this wrong? Should I have a different strategy to this? And could I have also attacher pbix-file to this? I used free sample data found from internet so could have also shared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you will have a Year column in your `dimDate` table, then it would be:

```
Q1 =
  CALCULATE(
    [All Orderamount],
    REMOVEFILTERS(),
    dimDate[QuarterNo] = 1 && dimDate[Year] IN DISTINCT(dimDate[Year])
  )
```

Alternative for readability only:

```
Q1 =
  var yrs = DISTINCT(dimDate[Year])
  RETURN
    CALCULATE(
      [All Orderamount],
      REMOVEFILTERS(),
      dimDate[QuarterNo] = 1 && dimDate[Year] IN yrs
    )
```

Comment: Ok so it worked! Thank you :)

But now when Iam figuring out "context transition" and learning... I have small trouble in understading:
"dimDate[Year] IN DISTINCT(dimDate[Year])"

"removefilters" clears all filters
"dimDate[QuarterNo] = 1" sets filter to check first quater

but how is it able to have year on filter back when we just cleared all filters from the context transiotion?

Comment: The `REMOVEFILTERS()` isn't applied to `DISTINCT(dimDate[Year])`, it is only applied to the calculation of `[All Orderamount]` - see updated answer above for an alternative that might help.

Comment: The first one worked already really good :) Thanks ;) For my learning if I'll think this like DISTINCT(dimDate[Year]) makes a new filter context thats applied to the visual? Would I be totally wrong?